# How pass the date pick by user (via showDatePicker) to new page in flutter without navigator

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

Tried to use Riverpod didn't work as I don't want to change the UI but use this variable on the second page as DOC id. I don't want to call this function again otherwise I define a custom  widget for it. Just need to access the date the user picks on the second page.WITHOUT a navigator as still there are actions that need to be done on the first page.

On a page user picks the date :

```
 final initalDate = DateTime.now();
    final newDate = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: initalDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 0),
        lastDate: DateTime.now());
    if (newDate == null) return;
```

As this is defined as Doc id in firestore , how can I access this on the second page without navigation?

```
class SugarPhotoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SugarPhotoPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<SugarPhotoPage> createState() => _SugarPhotoPageState();
}

class _SugarPhotoPageState extends State<SugarPhotoPage> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _photoStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('photos')
      .doc(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(newDate))
      .collection('Today Photos')
      .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _photoStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Something went wrong');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Text("Loading");
            }

            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return SafeArea(
                child: Center(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs
                        .map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                      Map<String, dynamic> data =
                          documentSnapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: Container(
                          height: 100,
                          width: 100,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: NetworkImage('${data['ImgUrl']}'),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            return const Text('Loading');
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Tried to use Riverpod didn't work  as I don't want to change the UI but use this variable  IN second page as DOC id .

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to share data using the navigator then you can create a single data source that shares the data between screens.

You can create a singleton class that contains a static variable that can be accessed throughout the app.

1 -> create a singleton class

```
class AppData {
  AppData._();

  static DateTime? userSelectedData;

}
```

2 -> update date on user selection

```
final initalDate = DateTime.now();
final newDate = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: initalDate,
    firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 0),
    lastDate: DateTime.now());
if (newDate == null) {return;}
else{
AppData.userSelectedData = newDate;
}
```

3-> Now you can access the date wherever you want without context by calling `AppData.userSelectedData`

if you want to save user selection after app is closed you can introduce Shared Preferences as well